# How to import JS scripts in React similar to how its done in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, es6-modules

What is the equivalent of `<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>` in React? I tried `import './js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js';` but it is not working.

Comment: You could import it in the `index.html` in `public` folder by using the script tag

Comment: where you are writing import statement? filename?

Comment: that's not react syntax.  that's es6 modules import/export syntax.  find a good tutorial on how to use es6 import export and es6 modules and learn how your bundling system works.  after you have something workable come back and post what you've tried.  you can use codesandbox.io to post it